# Which directories does WordPress attempt to create when updating core and installing plugins?

Tags: updates

Which directories does WordPress 4 attempt to create when updating core and installing or upgrading plugins?

The purpose of the question is to gain understanding of the update process and spread that knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's `wp-content/upgrade` plus it overwrites or creates new files for whatever you're actually updating as part of the process.